# How write correct regex

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have following Requirment
   User can enter multiple values with , seprated
    e.g. 10,20,30,35-40,45,50-55 //Valid

```
User can enter multiple values - seprated
e.g. 10,20-30,35-40 //Valid
e.g. 10,20-30,35-40,-1000 //Invalid
```

i have following RegEx

```
   ^
  (?:
     (?:[0-9]?\d|[0-9])(?:-[0-9]?\d|[0-9])?
  )
  (?:
     ,(?:[0-9]?\d|[0-9])(?:-[0-9]?\d|[0-9])?
  )*
$

I am validating following value 
10,20-30,35-40      Valid
01-50,              invalid
50                  Valid
500                 Valid
40-50,50-60,5,50    Valid
40-50,1234-4567     Invalid (Expected: this should be valid)
5-50                Valid
5,80                Valid
8,71                Valid
test and lol        Invalid
08,60               Valid
```

Please help me to write correct regex to achieve correct output.

Comment: Perhaps if you specified **what** your regex should do, we would at least have an idea about it.

Comment: what is so special about `5000`..do you want the digits to be in specific range

Comment: i have updated my question. please do let me know if require more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^\d+([,-]\d+)*$
```

`+` is a quantifier which matches preceding group or character **1** to many times..

`*` is a quantifier which matches preceding group or character **0** to many times..

`[xyz]` is a character class which matches a x **or** y **or** z

Comment: Nice answer. is it possible to validate first item should be less than or equal to second item? e.g. 10-20 is valid but 20-10 is invalid. my vote +1

Comment: @imdadhusen no, in regex everything is a `String`. You will need to actually parse the values and check them in you want to check relatives sizes. This can be easily done with capture groups.

Comment: @imdadhusen as Bris said..you can't do it in regex..follow the **KISS** principal..split the text and then check their order